# Snowflake Scala Connector(snowpark)

Tags: database, scala, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connector

I am new to scala and trying to create a snowflake connector in scala using snowflake snowpark scala library.

Here is my simple code

```
package com.abc.commons.rest.snowflake
import com.snowflake.snowpark._
import com.snowflake.snowpark.functions._

object ScalaConnector {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Replace the <placeholders> below.
    val configs = Map (
      "URL" -> "https://xxx.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
      "USER" -> "xxx",
      "PASSWORD" -> "xxx",
      "ROLE" -> "xxx",
      "WAREHOUSE" -> "xxx",
      "DB" -> "xxx",
      "SCHEMA" -> "xxx"
    )
    val session = Session.builder.configs(configs).create
    session.sql("show tables").show()
    session.close();
  }
}
```

I have provided correct credentials and then on running the above code in IntelliJ I am getting below errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.abc.commons.rest.snowflake.ScalaConnector$.main(ScalaConnector.scala:17)
    at com.abc.commons.rest.snowflake.ScalaConnector.main(ScalaConnector.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session$.getActiveSession(Session.scala:1204)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.SnowparkClientException.<init>(SnowparkClientException.scala:15)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ErrorMessage$.createException(ErrorMessage.scala:380)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ErrorMessage$.MISC_SCALA_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED(ErrorMessage.scala:340)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.Utils$.checkScalaVersionCompatibility(Utils.scala:243)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.Utils$.checkScalaVersionCompatibility(Utils.scala:233)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session$.<init>(Session.scala:1129)
    at com.snowflake.snowpark.Session$.<clinit>(Session.scala)
    ... 2 more
```

**libraryDependencies** I use in **`build.sbt`**

```
"com.snowflake" % "snowpark" % "1.4.0"
```

Can anyone point out the issue in my code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue with the code, you're just using an unsupported Scala version. From your stacktrace:

MISC_SCALA_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED

We only support Scala 2.12 as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/scala/prerequisites.html).

Comment: Still the same issue @Sergiu. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` this is 1st error which probably means there is some exception coming from the code side I think!.

Comment: Can you add again the full stacktrace? And have you used Scala 2.12?

Comment: yes, I am using Scala 2.12.9 and java 11